# How to start at end of map

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I want to be able to start at the end of a `std::map` so that the items at the end of the list are checked first, for example...

```
std::map<int> MapBasicExample;

MapBasicExample.insert(1);
MapBasicExample.insert(2);
MapBasicExample.insert(3);
MapBasicExample.insert(4);
MapBasicExample.insert(5);
```

When i use `MapBasicExample.begin()` it is the value "5" that is checked first, and i would like to from 1 - 5 in the loop first not from 5 - 1 like it does when using `MapBasicExample.begin()`, how can this be done?

Comment: [`std::map::rbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/rbegin)?

Comment: Your example is completely broken. Maps have keys _and_ values, and are inherently sorted in ascending order. So none of what you're saying makes any sense.

Comment: Presumably you mean `set`, not `map`; and that map should be ordered 1-5. In any case, use `rbegin` and `rend` to iterate backwards.

Comment: @  Lightness Races in Orbit, it was to better explain myself and what i wanted, it was not to present any type of code as you can clearly see in the example - therefore the question.  I got my answer so it seems it did make sense afterall.

Comment: @user2142260 -1 SO is not for anybody to get their answer, but to be useful to the community. For a question to be useful, it must satisfy a minimal standard. Yours doesn't and should be closed.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate the map in reverse order like this:

```
for (auto it = MapBasicExample.rbegin(); it != MapBasicExample.rend(); it++) {
    std::cout << it->first << " = " << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

Remember that map have keys and values. Your example looks like a set. The logic to iterate both of them in reverse order is similar, though.